# ImageDataGenerator directory

Tags: tensorflow, image-generation

I am working with te ImageDataGenerator in Tensorflow for labeling images.

I seem to be doing something wrong trying to point into my trainning directory, any ideas?

Thanks in advance

```
  from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    train_datagen =ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            'C:\Users\Ignacio\Documents\Python for Data Science\Tensorflow Exam\Horses or humans\train',
            target_size=(150, 150),
            batch_size=32,
            class_mode='binary')
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in particular? Check if you have specified the directory path correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check [instructions here](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/).

Your directory should have the structure:

```
main_directory/
...class_a/
......a_image_1.jpg
......a_image_2.jpg
...class_b/
......b_image_1.jpg
......b_image_2.jpg
```

Comment: That is ok. If I put the folder inside my project directory it works, but I can´t move it from there

Comment: If I put it elsewhere as the coda that I have written it won´t work...